# create nested structure using JAXB notations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<info>
     <contract>
       <symbol>IBM</symbol>
       <sectype>STK</sectype>
       <exchange>SMART</exchange>
       <currency>USD</currency>
    </contract>
    <order>
      <action>SELL</action>
      <quantity>100</quantity>
      <ordertype>LMT</ordertype>
      <imtprice>imtprice</imtprice>
      <transmit>false</transmit>
   </order>
</info>
```

I want to use jaxb annotations with existing java classes to create above XML input but i don't know how create nested xml structure based on Java classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> @XmlRootElement
>   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
>   @XmlType(propOrder =
>   {"contract", "order"})
>  public class Info
>   {
>    @XmlElement(required =
>   true)
>    private Contract
>   contract;
>   @XmlElement(required = true)
>   private Order order;
>        // Getters and setters
>  }

Another class:

> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
>   @XmlType(propOrder = {"symbol",
>   "sectype", "exchange",
>   "currency"})
>  public class
>   Contract {
>    @XmlElement(required
>   = true)
>    private String symbol;
>    @XmlElement(required =
>   true)
>    private String
>   sectype;
>    @XmlElement(required =
>   true)
>    private String
>   exchange;
>    @XmlElement(required
>   = true)
>    private String currency;
>  
> //Getters and
>   setters
> }

Create an order class the same way.

Comment: Un-annotated fields will be treated as @XmlElement, if you don't need to specify required=true (which corresponds to minOccurs="1" in the schema) then you don't need use as many @XmlElement annotations.

Comment: What should i write if i want 3 instance of <order> tag in xml instead of only one